# Proper use of offset function and for/while loop

Tags: vba, excel

Bit new to VBA. So, forgive me if it's pretty simple.
I am making an Excel form for various Companies' Registration.

My Excel records first column(A) as company_name where one has to give his/her company_name.

Column C has total no. of Employees in Company. (This includes permanent + Contract Employees).

Column D and E has Employees' Names who are permanent only.

So, Assume; My column C has value 5; column (D and E) may have 5 or less than 5 Employee names. (Strictly not more than 5 Employee Names. If those columns have more than 5 names; it should throw an error message in sheet2)

My next column F is designation. This can have values among '**Manager**','**Attender**','**Developer**','**Operator**','**CEO**' only and no other value is allowed. These values can be repeated too (for different employees as in below image)

[image: My_Excel]

For this I have written below code and it works fine.

```
Dim  celadr, celval, celadrI, celvalI, celadrN, celvalN As Variant

Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Select
    ' Selection.Clearformats
    For Each cell In Selection
        celadr = cell.Address
        celval = cell.Value
        celadrI = cell.Offset(0, 4).Address
        celvalI = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        celadrN = cell.Offset(0, 9).Address
        celvalN = cell.Offset(0, 9).Value

    If Len(celval) >= 1 Then
        If InStr(1, ("MANAGER,ATTENDER,DEVELOPER,OPERATOR,CEO,"), Trim(UCase(celval) & ",")) < 1 Then
            Range(celadr).Interior.Color = vbRed

            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = celval & "  The Designation is incorrect"
            strstr = "'" & shname & "'!" & Range(celadr).Address(0, 0)
            Sheets("Sheet2").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp), Address:="", SubAddress:=strstr

        End If
    End If       
    Next
```

Now my next requirement is; for each company, there should be atleast a single '**Manager**'.

If a certain company don't have manager, then I have to give message in 'Sheet2' as "Their should be atleast a single 'Manager' for this company" 
with a link to the correct cells in sheet1.

I am able to validate it when the 'Manager' is written in the same row in which Company_Name is written.

But, I don't have idea how to do it when 'Manager' is not written in the same row of Company_Name.

Below is my code which works only when Designation - 'Manager' is assumed to be written in the same row as that of Company_Name.

```
Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Select

    For Each cell In Selection
        celadr = cell.Address
        celval = cell.Value
    If Len(celval) >= 1 Then

            If Trim(cell.Offset(i, 5).Value) <> "Manager" Then 

    cell.Offset(i, 5).Interior.Color = vbRed

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = celval & "Their should be atleast a single 'Manager' for this company"
    strstr = "'" & shname & "'!" & Range(celadr).Address(0, 0)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp), Address:="", SubAddress:=strstr
    End If

    End If
    Next
```

I tried to write the code as below to validate when 'Manager' is written on different Row than the Company_Name.

(I have commented the part which was giving me error.)

```
Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Select
' Selection.Clearformats
For Each cell In Selection
    celadr = cell.Address
    celval = cell.Value
If Len(celval) >= 1 Then
        ' For i = 0 To cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        If Trim(cell.Offset(i, 5).Value) <> "Manager" Then 'And cell.Offset(1, 0).Value < 1 Then
        ' Do Nothing
' Else
cell.Offset(i, 5).Interior.Color = vbRed

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = celval & "Their should be atleast a single 'Manager' for this company"
strstr = "'" & shname & "'!" & Range(celadr).Address(0, 0)
Sheets("Sheet2").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp), Address:="", SubAddress:=strstr
End If

' Next i

' If cell.Offset(1, 0).Value >= 1 Then
' End If
 End If
 Next
```

Can anyone guide me how I can make proper use of offset function and for loop/while loop/find function to verify each company has atleast a single Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to determine if something is missing or not it is **generaly easier to set a boolean** to use it afterwards to apply the correct procedure.

This should help you :

```
Dim HasManager As Boolean, _
    LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Select
'Selection.Clearformats

For Each cell In Selection
    celadr = cell.Address
    celval = cell.Value
    If Len(celval) >= 1 Then
        HasManager = False
        'For i = 0 To cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        i = 0
        Do While HasManager = False And _
        (cell.Offset(i, 0).Value = "" Or cell.Offset(i, 0).Value = celval) And _
        cell.Offset(i, 0).Row <= LastRow + 1
            If LCase(Trim(cell.Offset(i, 5).Value)) = "manager" Then HasManager = True
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        If HasManager Then
            'The company has at least one Manager
        Else
            'The company doesn't have any Manager
            cell.Offset(i - 1, 5).Interior.Color = vbRed

            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = celval & "Their should be atleast a single 'Manager' for this company"
            strstr = "'" & shname & "'!" & Range(celadr).Address(0, 0)
        End If
    Else
    End If
Next cell
```